# c - linked list/libxml - search next element of certain type and check for end of list

Tags: c, linked-list, libxml2

I am trying to go find the next part of the linked list that is  `XML_ELEMENT_NODE` and stop when its found or I reach the end of the list:

```
do
{
    cur = cur->next;
} while (cur->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE && cur != NULL);
```

So I get the`next` first, because if I check first I would be stuck with the same part and would not progress. Problem is when I reached the end `cur == NULL`, I can not check the type because I am at `NULL` and can't get the type obviously. Is there an elegant solution for that, because all I can think of requires substitution variables that I set in the loop so I can check them in `while()`. And `break`is not an option I think.

Comment: What do you think happens if `curr` is NULL in the controlling expression? Please search for "short circuit evaluation". A _null pointer_ does not point to anything.  Why are you using the inclusive loop anyway? Tired of using the exclusive one?

Comment: @Olaf For some reason I thought c has no short circuit evaluation. But it always does this? Then I would only need to switch both expressions, I think. With inclusive loop you mean the `do{}while`? I did this because I need it to be executed once. I could do with `while{}` but then I would have to do it beforehand.

Comment: And regarding the NULL. I think `cur != NULL` is false (0) but `cur->type` tries to acces something that is not there. If it is equal to `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`is not relevant.

Comment: Refer the answers below - neither check the validity of `cur` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should folow a certain flow of iterations. In general, you must **never** dereference a *null pointer*, so you always have to ensure `curr` is not a *null pointer* (briefly: `curr != NULL`).

If, for any reason, you need to get the next element first, you should use:

```
while ( curr != NULL ) {

    curr = curr->next;
    if ( (curr != NULL) && (curr->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) )
        break;
}
```

But the better way would be always to operate on the current node (that's why you call the pointer like that). If you **know** curr is not `NULL` (determined by the preceeding code), you can use:

```
// from some previous code, you have:
curr = curr->next;

... (do something unrelated, i.e. do not dereference curr if null-pointer)
while ( (curr != NULL) && (curr->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE) ) {
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

After any of the loops, you have to test `curr != NULL` to catch the end-of-list condition before dereferencing `curr`.

Note that `curr` is always the current node (the one you are starting with/working on.

Comment: Given the fact that with short circuit evaluation, this solves the problem I originally had. Why is a repetive call to cur = cur->next in the while better than do-while? Is there any downside of using do-while? Solution because you were the first with.

Comment: @KamiKaze: Do you use a hammer to remove a screw? Or a screwdriver to "insert" a nail? It's just not a good choise her, as you have to check for _null pointer_ **before** you dereference `currr` to get the next entry. the exclusive loop is most times the better choice; some langauges (e.g. Python) don't even have an inclusive loop. Also, you can emulate an inclusive loop by using `break`, as in my first snippet, where I actually have to test on both "ends" of the loop. I'd recommend to get some paper and a pencil, draw a short list and traverse the list by hand with my code.

Comment: I can follow your code fine. Thing is the second one seems exactly like a do-while thats why I asked. The first one has the advantage of checking before hand (which is already done in my case). But break is a jump which has to be avoided as far as I know.

Comment: @KamiKaze are you overlooking the sequence of the tests? The `NULL` value is checked *before* its object as was commented variously.

Comment: Hmm, after you said: yes, you are right (acknowledged, I did not notice - shame on me). That construct is not the normal one, so that's why I did not think about. I actually meant it a bit different than is appears. Editing...

Comment: @WeatherVane: He is actually right about the second snippet (ashwes on my head), if you really think of having the initial `curr = curr->next;` as it was written. However, I actually meant to have it advanced from some earier code. Hope the edit makes this clear now.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while(cur->next !=NULL && cur->next->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
    cur = cur->next;
}
// at this point, the next element, if it exists, is of type XML_ELEMENT_NODE
// if it doesn't exist, cur->next will be NULL
cur = cur->next;
```

Comment: That would leave me stuck on the same node as it is an XML_ELEMENT_NODE

Comment: I edited my answer.  If I understand what you are trying to do, this should work.  as Weather Vane points out though, it is a good idea to validate your pointers before doing anything with them.

Comment: Some Pointer-Fu, but I think this would also get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check whether `cur` is good in the first place. I suggest

```
while (cur != NULL) {
    if (cur->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        break;
    cur = cur->next;
}
if (cur != NULL) {
// ... success
}
```

**EDIT** since OP says he has already checked `cur` and also doesn't like `break` this is my revision, but this *still* checks `cur` at the start not the end of the loop.

```
while (cur != NULL && cur->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
    cur = cur->next;
}
if (cur != NULL) {
// ... success
}
```

Comment: cur is good in the first place, that is a given because of the previous code. And I was taught very often `break` (jumps in generall) outside of switch/case is bad so I don't use it.

Comment: So now you tell us, but be cautious, assume nothing. Your problem statement (with comment on another answer) isn't great. I guess you want to stop at the node that contains `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`.

Comment: At this point cur was already processed. Other checks were done beforehand.

Comment: @KamiKaze I have edited. It never hurts to check a pointer before use, no matter how confident you are it is good, and in this case, there is no time penalty, since it needs checking anyway.

Comment: The basic problem solver was Olaf with his short circuit evaluation, which the rest of you also used. I would say it is checked twice and this takes more time, but I will not argue against safe coding. So thank you and I will think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the conditions around the `&&` operator :

```
do
{
    cur = cur->next;
} while (cur != NULL && cur->type != XML_ELEMENT_NODE);
```

This is because if the first condition is `false` (`cur` is `NULL`), it will stop, as the `&&` operator stops if the first condition does not evaluate to `true`. As a result, if `cur` is `NULL`, it will stop evaluating the condition and not try and dereference the nyll pointer

Comment: Mind telling me why he got a -1? It's the exact solution for my problem,even if it is the one Olaf was talking about. +1 for fairness, as long noone tells me why the -1 was okay. Remember a check beforehand was not necessary.